# Русское издание, использующее "высокий" язык

Tags: словоупотребление

Есть американские издания, такие как *The New Yorker*, которые используют "высокие" академические и литературные слова, которые понимают только образованные или начитанные люди. Какой русскоязычный журнал или газета публикует статьи в подобном стиле? (В таком издании можно было бы встретить такие слова как "эскапизм", "визави" и т.д.)

Comment: Думаю, что кроме как в теологических и философских толстых журналах такого вы нигде не найдёте. Просто некому было бы подобную периодику читать. :)

Comment: @Yellow Sky ты хотел сказать "философских в кавычках"? Потому что ни одного реально философского журнала в России нет.

Comment: @Anixx - Вообще-то мы с вами лично не знакомы. И я ничего не хотел сказать, я сказал то, что думаю. [Вот это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B#.D0.9D.D0.B0_.D1.80.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BC_.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8B.D0.BA.D0.B5) что? [Это что](http://www.phisci.ru/index.php/rjps-the-last-issue/93-issues/2014-issues/2014-02-issue/267-rjps-2014-02-falev), не тянет на «реальную» статью по философии? Или, может, вы думаете, что журнал «Эпистемология и философия науки» пишет не о философии?

Comment: @Yellow Sky Для ТСа эта статья подойдет, согласен. Но если честно, по опубликованному началу больше похожа на имитацию философии.

Comment: Мне кажется, вопрос хороший, особенно для Сайнфелда :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В России издается много литературных, научных и публицистических журналов, которые по своей цели похожи на The New Yorker, но ни один из них не популярен сейчас так, как NY. Многие из них были созданы в 19 или начале 20 века. Например, есть журнал Новый Мир, который мои родители выписывали и читали в 80-х и начала 90-х, есть Вестник Европы. Есть много специализированных журналов, которые используют академический язык или публикуют литературные произведения, я, например, раньше читала Полис и Вопросы философии. Эти журналы, правда, редко можно найти в обычных газетных киосках. Есть аналитические, популярные издания, вроде Итоги, Ъ-Власть, или Эксперт, но сложно сказать, что они используют "высокий" язык.

Answer (score 2):

Как справедливо пишет @dariamikhaylova, в России сложилась (и все еще жива) культура и традиция "толстых" журналов. Особенно "высокого" языка вы там не найдете, но это точно НЕ бульварная пресса. В основном это литература и поэзия, но есть и публицистика. Много из них (в том числе *Новый Мир*) выложено в интернете - please see [here](http://magazines.russ.ru/).

Такой формат, как в журнале *The New Yorker* (публицистические статьи + рассказ + текущая реклама и информация) можно найти в журнале [*Сноб*](http://www.snob.ru/) (его фокус - русскоязычная диаспора). Кстати говоря, онлайн-версия этого журнал не позволяет комментировать, если у вас нет (достаточно дорогой) подписки - поэтому многие комментарии действительно добавляют к теме статьи и развивают ее.